# Pulling six christmas crackers from a pool of six people

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

**A family of six has six Christmas crackers to pull. Each person will pull two crackers, each with a different person. In how many different ways can this be done?**

So far I have found $20$ possibilities, because the six members can be separated into two groups of $3$. Each group of 3 has one distinct way of pulling crackers, and there are ${6 \choose 3}$ ways of selecting two groups of 3, giving $20$ ways of cracking crackers. However I'm stuck on how to find more from here onwards. The desired answer is $70$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea. However, the number of ways dividing $6$ people into two groups of three is not 20. It is 10. You may want to read more about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179515/division-of-items-into-groups).

The other case you're missing is when the six people form a cycle of their own - i.e. if you place the family members on a round table, each person forms a pair with their neighbour. The number of ways in which this is done is $\frac{5!}{2} = 60.$

Thus, the answer is $$10 + 60 = 70$$