# A mother bought $10$ story books for her $3$ children. The youngest gets $2$ books and the other two get $4$ each.

Tags: combinatorics

A mother bought $10$ story books for her $3$ children. The youngest gets $2$ books and the other two get $4$ each. Find the number of ways she can pack them as gifts.

There are $10 \choose 2$ ways to pack the two books, $8 \choose 4$ ways to pack the first set of four books, and then $4 \choose 4$ ways to pack the second set of four books. Then there are $3 \choose 1$ ways to arrange the sets of books for a total of $3*{10 \choose 2}*{8 \choose 4}*{4\choose 4}$ ways to pack the books as gifts. Does this make sense? Is this the proper technique for this type of problem?

Comment: It made sense until you multiplied by three.  Choose which books the youngest child receives, choose which four books the next youngest child receives, and give the remaining four books to the oldest child.

Comment: I do not see why you should multiply by $3$ in the end. Other that that, it is correct.

Comment: I multiplied by $3$ because there are three ways to arrange the packaged books. I suppose this does not matter. So then this is just $10!\over 2!4!4!$.

Comment: All arrangements have already been counted when you did ${10 \choose 2} \cdot {8 \choose 4}$.

Comment: Even if you were arranging packaged books, that is $3!$ ways. But one of them cannot get $4$ books so that makes it $2!$. So in either case, I cannot understand the logic of $3$.

Comment: I will clear you doubt for why you shouldn't multiply by 3. In my solution when I separated 2 books for the first child, we have to now divide into 2 groups of equal sizes after dividing those I multiplied by $2!$ which distributes the 4 books among 2 child ( Now these 2 child can be A or B, B or C, C or A ) the 2 book slot(left one) will automatically go to the left child.

Comment: @MathLover you can't understand the logic of $3$ because it is wrong... I made a mistake. What you said makes sense though. Thank you.

Comment: @VyomYadav thank you so much, your explanation cleared up my doubts/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the story books are different-
The books for the first child can be selected in $C^{10}_2$ ways.
**Now there are 8 books left so the principle of division when group size is same will be applied.**
We have to make equal groups of 4, so the no of ways to do it-
$$\frac{C_4^8.C^4_4}{2!}$$
This is may sound confusing but we have to do it (dividing by $2!$) to distinguish the groups.
Now we have to distribute this lot between two children, s0
$$\frac{C_4^8.C^4_4}{2!}.2!=C_4^8.C^4_4$$
So the total no of ways are-
$$C^{10}_2.C_4^8.C^4_4$$
**NOTE-**
I could have proceeded without using the principle for division when group size is same but I think that's very crucial and we should observe it here so we are benefited in the future also.

EDIT-
I would advise you to read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179515/division-of-items-into-groups) for knowing more about division of items in groups of same/different size.